# Creating an IF statement in Excel to return the value of a function if it doesn't return an error. If it does, replace the string with 0

Tags: excel

I have an excel function using an add-in that totals the values in a database using a function. When there are no values to return, it shows "[-11059] No Good Data For Calculation". This implies that there is no data for this time period, which is fine. However, I would like it to replace that string with 0 to clean up the form.

I have tried ISERROR, but that only works on standard excel errors. I'm not sure if the "IF" statement is the best way to go here. Any ideas out there?

Comment: Does the add-in return the string enclosed in double-quotes or is that just for Posting??

Comment: That's just for posting, it does not return the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If `F(...)` is your function call, you could try

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(F(...)),F(...),0)
```

Comment: ISNUMBER was the key, I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome! If it works out for you, could I trouble you to mark this as the answer?